# How to turn content from a text file into an integer variable

Tags: python, helper

I am fairly new to programming and am trying to create a script. What I am trying to do is I have data written to a text file in this format `x, y\n`. I then want to get that same content from the text file and assign it to a variable as an integer so I could use for example as graph cords. I.E `turtle.goto(variable)`.  Simplified: I have data that is `1400, 800`. I write that to a text file with a newline. I then want to read that same line and have those two numbers as integers for a variable. turtle.goto(variable) = turtle.goto(1400, 800).

```
config.txt contains "1400,1800\n"
file = open('config.txt')
content = file.readlines()
commentz = content[0].strip('\n')   
pyautogui.click(commentz)
```

Comment: Post code as text, not images.

Comment: Please post some example lines of the contents of the file

Answer (score 2):

Read the lines of `config.txt` file.
Remove the whitespace and `\n` characters from every line with `strip()`.
Split the numbers into `x` and `y` variables with `split(',')`.
Convert `x` and `y` to int values with `int(x)` and `int(y)`.

```py
with open('config.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        x, y = line.strip().split(',')
        pyautogui.click(int(x), int(y))
```

Comment: how can i apply this if there is multiple lines and want them to be named differently?

Answer (score 0):

Split on `", "` to separate the `x` and `y`, then use `map` to convert each part to an `int`.

Finally, use `*` to unpack them as separate arguments.

```py
pyautogui.click(*map(int, commentz.split(', ')))
```

Or written more explicitly:

```py
commentz = content[0].rstrip('\n')
x, y = map(int, commentz.split(', '))
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please past code as text. Don't use images.
Secondly what you are looking for is this

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        numbers = [int(xx) for xx in line.strip("\n").split(",")]
        # assumption they are two numbers
        x, y = numbers
```

So you will read the lines from your text files. loop on those lines. then you will do list iterable and every item you will get from splitting on commas. You will convert to int using this builtin function `int("string")`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
  data = f.readlines()
  a, b = data[0].split(', ')
```

When you use `a` and `b` variables you need to convert them to int:

```
int(a)
int(b)
```

If you got multiple lines:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
  data = f.readlines()
  for i in data:
     a, b = i[0].split(', ')
     pyautogui.click(int(a),int(b))
```